# Parsing XML attributes with nested namespaces with lxml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, alexa-skills-kit

I want to parse the country codes attributes in RankByCountry. How can I do it?

means- print a list ['GB', 'US', 'O']

```
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"><aws:OperationRequest><aws:RequestId>122bfdc6-ae8e-d2a2-580e-3841ab33b966</aws:RequestId></aws:OperationRequest><aws:UrlInfoResult><aws:Alexa>
 <aws:TrafficData>
  <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">androidjones.com/</aws:DataUrl>
  <aws:RankByCountry>
    <aws:Country Code="GB">
      <aws:Rank>80725</aws:Rank>
      <aws:Contribution>
        <aws:PageViews>30.6%</aws:PageViews>
        <aws:Users>41.3%</aws:Users>
      </aws:Contribution>
    </aws:Country>
    <aws:Country Code="US">
      <aws:Rank>354356</aws:Rank>
      <aws:Contribution>
        <aws:PageViews>39.1%</aws:PageViews>
        <aws:Users>28.9%</aws:Users>
      </aws:Contribution>
    </aws:Country>
    <aws:Country Code="O">
      <aws:Rank/>
      <aws:Contribution>
        <aws:PageViews>30.2%</aws:PageViews>
        <aws:Users>29.8%</aws:Users>
      </aws:Contribution>
    </aws:Country>
  </aws:RankByCountry>
 </aws:TrafficData>
</aws:Alexa></aws:UrlInfoResult><aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode></aws:ResponseStatus></aws:Response></aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

already tried--

```
namespaces = {"aws": "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"}
RankByCountry = tree.xpath("//aws:Country/Code", namespaces=namespaces)
```

but no luck.

and also:

```
for country in tree.xpath('//Country'):
   for attrib in country.attrib:
      print '@' + attrib + '=' + country.attrib[attrib]
```

Comment: Did you try something out?

Comment: yes, but don't know how to access the attribute, just the data...

Comment: my bad I thought you meant the use of `regex` !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document looks weird, since it is using the `aws` namespace prefix twice. You need to use the more specific namespace, since this overwrites the global namespace with prefix `aws`. Actually you are doing this right.

The problem is the xpath expression itself, it should look like this:

```
for country in tree.xpath('//aws:RankByCountry/aws:Country/@Code', namespaces=namespaces):
    print(country)
```

Note that `<aws:RankByCountry>` has no `Code` attribute, but `<aws:Country>` has.

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl . you can change `root` to `tree` to be consistent with my code.